# Run application with arguments from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I have a C# console application. I currently have a scheduled task setup to run the application and it provides two command line arguments, shown below.

```
/AUTORUN FALSE /INTRADAY FALSE
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible to have an Excel run the C# console application and pass command line arguments? For example an excel spreadsheet contains a button that when clicked will start my C# console application?

**Update**

I am using the code below. The console application loads but it does appear to read my command line arguements

```
Sub TestConsole()

Dim id As Integer

id = Shell("""C:\Shared\Blah\Visual  Studio\MyProg\bin\Release\MyProg.exe"" /HOLDING_CHANGES TRUE", vbNormalFocus)


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: No I don't know how to. I can control Excel from C# and run macros etc but not sure how to run a console application from Excel. When I search google the pages are all about C# calling an excel macro - which I know how to do.

Comment: You create a Shell object in VBA and then use the Run or Execute method I don't remember now which one it was.. In the Run/Execute you provide a String like if you were running it from CMD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the VB [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function in a macro.

Sample from MSDN:

```
Dim procID As Integer 
' Run calculator.
procID = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
' The preceding path is for Windows XP. 
' The Windows 2000 path is C:\WINNT\system32\calc.exe.
```

Comment: thanks - it does load my console application. However I can't seem to pass any command line arguments I've just updated my post with the code I'm trying

Comment: @mHelpMe: Did you read the article? It describes a way to pass in parameters too.

Comment: yes I was trying to copy the -a -q. I took that to be the arguments they were passing. My understanding was that the arguments are strings passed in the first parameter of the Shell function?

Comment: That is correct. Are you sure they don't come in your app?

Comment: when I run the app ignoring excel its fine. Have to be honest not sure I how when running the console app from excel how I can check the parameter values been passed?

Comment: They should be there in the `args` of your `Main` function.

Comment: sorry it does work. I forgot to rebuild my program in release mode!